# How to tell asdf to use the directory of the .asd file as root directory of project

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I am trying to load my project using a self-made .asd file, but somehow asdf does not recognize that the .asd file should also be the root-directory of the project and therefore resuling in an error like `failed to find the TRUENAME of /home/$USER/rel-path-to-file` where `rel-path-to-file` is the path to the corresponding file, relative to the loaded .asd file.

This is what I did:

```
(push "path-to-project-directory-of-asd-file" asdf:*central-registry*)
```

then

```
(asdf:load-system 'project-name)
```

It DOES find my .asd file but somehow not the .lisp files it shall load.

The asdf has been configured and installed by quicklisp. Therefore I also "installed" the project into quicklisp using a symlink, this worked as well. It DOES find the .asd file using `ql:quickload :name` but still doesn't use the directory containing the .asd file as the project-root.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @wvxvw add this as an answer, it was the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lisp pathnames are historically such that they require you to add a slash after directory name (I was told this is so due to the operating systems which were created before I was even born), so in order to tell Lisp that you target a directory you must end the name with the slash.

Comment: More precisely, CL pathnames have multiple fields including the directory and the name (among others).  The final slash (which, in a logical pathname, could be a final semicolon) is necessary so that the system knows that the whole namestring is a directory, rather than a directory followed by a filename.

Answer (score 1):

See asdf:system-relative-pathname.